# Importing a module in sibling dir while being executed as a __main__ program

Tags: python, python-2.7

On Python 2.7 I have the following:

```
$ tree dir1
dir1
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── dir2
│   ├── File1.py
│   ├── File1.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
└── dir3
    ├── File2.py
    ├── File2.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __init__.pyc

2 directories, 10 files



$ cat dir1/dir2/File1.py
print  __name__ + " imported successfully"
def fun():
    print "fun"

$ cat dir1/dir3/File2.py #case1
if __name__ != '__main__':
    from dir1.dir2 import File1
    print "worked"
else:
    from ..dir2 import File1
```

or

```
$ cat dir1/dir3/File2.py #case2
if __name__ != '__main__':
    from dir1.dir2 import File1
    print "worked"
else:
    from dir1.dir2 import File1

$ pwd
/Users/abc
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dir1.dir3.File2
dir1.dir2.File1 imported successfully
worked
```

But when I do:

```
$ python dir1/dir3/File2.py #case1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir1/dir3/File2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..dir2 import File1
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

or

```
$ python dir1/dir3/File2.py #case2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir1/dir3/File2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dir1.dir2 import File1
ImportError: No module named dir1.dir2
```

Why the error and what are the non-hacky, pythonic, standard ways of doing this?

Comment: Simply don't execute a file from within a package. Turn the file into a separate script and store (and execute) it outside the package.

Comment: @Evert It has to be in the package. Its a restriction I cannot change.

Comment: You mean it is supposed to be run as a script/executable, but it has to be inside the actual package? That is a really odd (bad design) setup, i.m.o.  (For example, you'd have to run it as `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dir1/dir3/File2.py`, instead of just entering `File2.py` on the cmdline). I'd be curious why this restriction exists.

Comment: @Evert Looks like you got it wrong. Please go over my post one more time.

Comment: I see that you execute this: `python dir1/dir3/File2.py`. Which to me appears you're executing a module as a script inside a package; and thus my first comment: don't do that (or rather, why would you do that? Why not store the script, or script part, outside the package?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have **init**.py, the whole thing becomes a module at the dir1 level.

So you can use relative imports:

```
from ..dir2 import File1
```

However, this would occur by importing it at the package level, at the dir1 level. If you aren't going to use a package as a package, you need something "hacky". And by hacky, we just mean telling it where to actually import the directory. Just add it to sys.path, you can pop it later (if you are worried about the path becoming too crowded for some reason). Otherwise, there is nothing to guide the import: it cannot rely on the package interface within a "non-package", since you are not using the package as one.

Import the module and then just have file2 import as follows.

If there was no **init**.py or you don't want to execute it at the package level, so one way would be just to add the dir1 directory to the path and then import the file and the names inside.

Example:

```
import os
import sys

FILE = os.path.realpath(__file__)
HOME = os.path.dirname(FILE)
sys.path.append(HOME)

from dir2 import File1
```

You could also use relative paths, and just simply do:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('..')

from dir2 import File1
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Intra Package References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) from the tutorial. It says

> Note that both explicit and implicit relative imports are based on the
>   name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is
>   always "**main**", modules intended for use as the main module of a
>   Python application should always use absolute imports.

So relative imports would not work. You need to make sure your package `dir1` is in the PYTHONPATH and then you do:

```
from dir1.dir2 import File1
```

Comment: The problem is that running `python dir1/dir3/File2.py` will not allow the interpreter to use relative imports, I don't know the details though. You have to use absolute imports in `File2.py` when it is used as your *main* module.

Comment: I used absolute imports as well, still an error. Please see above.

Comment: Is your `dir1` or the current working directory in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: None of them are in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: And that's what needs to be changed ;) - When `File2.py` is your *main* module, it does not know it's part of the dir1 package, Python does not know that a package `dir1` exists if it is not in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81442/discussion-between-abc-and-bernhard).